# Passenger+flask and URL escaping

Tags: python, flask, passenger, dreamhost

I'm writing an application in Flask, to be deployed on Dreamhost via Passenger. I have a setup such that I can run locally using `./run.py` (`env` is my virtualenv directory):

```
#!env/bin/python

from my_website import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

and deploying to Dreamhost works with the following `passenger_wsgi.py`:

```
#!env/bin/python
import sys, os
INTERP = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'env', 'bin', 'python')
if sys.executable != INTERP:
    os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
from my_website import app as application
```

Most stuff works just fine. *However*, I'm running into a problem where Passenger isn't decoding the URL's `PATH_INFO` as WSGI is supposed to do.  For example, I have a route set up (in `my_website/__init__.py`:

```
app.add_url_rule('/example/<key>', 'examplepage', examplepage.show_page)
```

For pages with simple keys, this works just fine on both Passenger and running locally. However, if I go to, for example, `example.com/example/test%20key`, on my local development system `examplepage.show_page` gets called with `key='test key'`, as expected, but via Passenger it gets called with `key='test%20key'`.

It appears that Flask's built-in HTTP server is URL-decoding the `PATH_INFO` before it even gets to Flask's URL parser, so as a result, `%2F` characters get prematurely decoded as well; since Flask expects the URL to already be URL-decoded at that point, it is not URL-decoding the individual parsed-out path components. However, Passenger+WSGI is preserving `PATH_INFO`, and thus the URL-encoded characters remain URL-encoded (which appears to be a bug in Passenger's WSGI implementation).

So, what is the simplest way to get the behavior consistent between Passenger and `./run.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work well (in `passenger_wsgi.py`), although there might be something amiss:

```
from my_website import app

# hackish way to apply WSGI's url decoding in Passenger
import urllib2
def application(environ, start_response):
    environ["PATH_INFO"] = urllib2.unquote(environ["PATH_INFO"])
    return app(environ, start_response)
```

One notable issue is that this means that `%2f` is no longer handled correctly, when it could have been through Passenger; however, handling it correctly would require making massive changes to Flask that would be incompatible on the vast majority of WSGI stacks.

Comment: Per https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/900 apparently the problem is that WSGI specifies that PATH_INFO should be urldecoded up-front, and Passenger is just not abiding by the WSGI spec.